# How to avoid the web application framework conflicts

Tags: jquery, css, visual-studio-2010

I am using visual studio 2010
I create web application using two web design frameworks **( groundwork css

and jquery easyUi )**

I include both frameworks in my project like

```
 <link href="css/groundwork.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <link href="css/easyui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Then I use one framework class to the element like

```
<div class="**GroudWork class**"></div>
<div class="**EasyUi class**"></div>
```

Then this design is conflicted by another framework class(**EasyUI framework**)...

Pls Tell me.. . How to include both frameworks in my project Without conflict each other..

Answer (score 0):

change the order of your css files.. Like this

```
<link href="css/easyui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
<link href="css/groundwork.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Depending upon the specificity of the selectors, order may not matter.

Comment: i reorder the css files... but there is no change takes place